# Kafka Producer Code FailedToSendMessageException

Tags: apache-kafka, producer

Producing Messages using Kafka

```
    import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException;
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;





public class KafkaProducer {

    private static Producer<String, String> producer;
    public KafkaProducer()
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("metadata.broker.list","localhost:2181");
        props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("request.required.acks","1");

        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
        producer = new Producer<String,String>(config);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if(args.length<2)
        {
            System.err.println("Usage: KafkaProducer TopicName MessageCount");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String topic = args[0];
        int messageCount = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        KafkaProducer kafka = new KafkaProducer();
        kafka.publishMessage(topic,messageCount);

    }

    private void publishMessage(String topic, int messageCount)
    {
        for(int mcount=0;mcount<messageCount;mcount++)
        {
            String runtime = new Date().toString();
            String msg = "Message Published Time -" + runtime;
            System.out.println(msg);

            KeyedMessage<String,String> data = new KeyedMessage<String,String>(topic,msg);
            producer.send(data);

        }
        producer.close();
    }

}
```

While running this program using eclipse, i am getting the following exception:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Message Published Time -Fri Jul 10 13:05:20 IST 2015
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at KafkaProducer.publishMessage(KafkaProducer.java:52)
    at KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:39)
```

The Zookeeper service started and Broker Started and Topic created. Consumer is also ready.

Can any one help me for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the new KafkaProducer briefly described in the [kafka docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerapi).

Note importing `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*` instead of `kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer` something like:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

public class KafkaProducerTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        // set up Kafka producer
        KafkaProducer<String,String> kafkaProducer;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());

        // instantiate the producer
        kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<String,String>(props);

        // add data to kafka
        ProducerRecord<String,String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String,String>("topic", "test key", "test value");
        kafkaProducer.send(producerRecord);

        // close producer
        kafkaProducer.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check that your Kafka server is running on the same port which is used by producer API ?

Generally Kafka clusters run on port 9092. If this is case with your setup, use the same port in producer configuration. Your producer is using port 2181. Probably that is a mistake.